# Image/matrix manipulation in R

Tags: r

I have two images:

```
m1 <- matrix(replicate(width * height, sample(0:1, 1)), width)
m2 <- matrix(replicate(width * height, sample(0:1, 1)), width)
img1 <- Image(m, colormode='Grayscale')
img2 <- Image(m, colormode='Grayscale')
```

and I want to create 3rd image by evaluating pixel values of the first two. So far I'm doing that with:

```
for (j in 1:height) {
  for (i in 1:width) {
    if ((img1[i, j] == 0) | (img2[i, j] == 0)) { 
      img3[i, j] <- 0 ...
```

I believe there should be a faster and more 'R way' of doing this, but I can't find it. So far, I came down to using apply (could only provide matrix element value without row and column) and outer (function could get row and column, but not element itself) and I would like to get all three.

Suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `m3 <- ifelse(m1 == 0 | m2 == 0, 0, 1)` ? Which packages are you using, `Image()`?

Comment: Can you provide a small example and the expected result? You can calculate with matrices and perhaps there's a smart "maths" way of approaching this.